# Accidentally deleted the device node /dev/sda1

Tags: ubuntu, disk

I was cleaning up my system and obviously got a little carried away. I ended up running: `sudo rm -rf /dev/sda1`. I can still see it running `lsblk` and `df -h` that `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/`, however it does not exists as special device under `/dev/`.
I can't reboot this server.

```
# lsblk
sda       8:0    0    50G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0  49.9G  0 part /
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `sudo mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1`

Comment: perhaps `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` then just `w` to write and exit - not sure but it won't hurt

Comment: @JaromandaX I took the liberty of expanding on your comment a bit with the why and how and posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Shadur - all good, I wasn't going to definitively say I was right because that would mean testing :p

Comment: The `/dev` directory tree is on a `devtmpfs` filesystem, which is a special type of a RAM disk. All the contents of `/dev` are recreated on every boot, so if you reboot your server or it would happen to lose power while `/dev/sda1` is missing, it would be automatically recreated on reboot, *just like it happens on every boot*.

Comment: @telcoM That's *usually* the case on *most* distros these days. I prefer not to generalize. :)

Comment: @Shadur The question was tagged "ubuntu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **Don't panic**.

You did not, in fact, erase your entire drive. All your data is still there, as evidenced by the fact that your system is still working.

All you did was delete the device file that linux, like most Unices, uses to identify and address that partition directly, and by and large the only times it needs to do that is when mounting or modifying the partition.

If your system is even remotely modern, chances are that it uses `udev` or something similar to automatically populate `/dev/` during boot time and things will continue to work fine, but just for your own surety I'd recommend taking Jaromanda's advice and recreate the node by running `sudo mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1`

Then make sure its permissions are set properly with the following commands:

```
sudo chown root.disk /dev/sda1
sudo chmod 660 /dev/sda1
```

**EDIT** A bit more clarification, as requested:

The `mknod` command does exactly what it says on the tin - it **m**a**k**es a device **nod**e. In this particular case, you tell it to create a **b** block device with major number 8 and minor number 1, which happens to translate to "The first partition of the first SCSI device presenting as a disk".

(For more explanation on device nodes, [this tutorial](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/?page_id=252) is informative but a bit outside the scope of this question)

Comment: before I do anything.
What does the `mknod` do? More specifically what does the "8" and "1" mean? I found this: This command creates the /dev/fd2 special file that is a special block file with the major device number 1 and the minor device number 2.
However, what does major and minor device mean?

Comment: look at the output of lsblk ... `sda1    8:1` ... see the `8:1` and what they are? .. i.e. `MAJ:MIN`